# Is there a possibility to calculate the velocity of a car if I just have the GPS data and my acceleration?

Tags: integration, matlab

I already tried the integration of acceleration, but the values I got where not realistic.

for that I used https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumtrapz.html

```
vx.data = cumtrapz(ax.data);    %integration of acceleration
vy.data = cumtrapz(ay.data);           
vz.data = cumtrapz(az.data);           
vx.time = ax.time;
vy.time = ay.time;
vz.time = az.time;
```

[image]

Is there any other posibility? Maybe with the GPS data?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered using a Kalman filter?

Comment: I would move this question to http://dsp.stackexchange.com

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo no I didn't. I'll have a look.

Comment: What to google: "sensor fusion", "GPS/INS".